# WCF service no response on production

Tags: wcf, timeout, block, production

I have a WCF webservice which makes calls to the SQLPlus/SQLLoader process using the **System.Diagnostics.Processus** class.
In both the unitary and acceptance environments, this service returns a response (successful or not) to the caller on time (time less than that defined in SendTimeOut ).

On the other hand in Production I noticed that this service finishes the processing as it should BUT it does not return a response and falls into TimeOut on the caller side.

It seems to me that the external process called from the service is blocked by the Production environment and does not close, which causes a deadlock.

Does anyone have an explanation of the possible reasons of blocking external proccess in such environment?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a difference in configuration between your production environment and other environments? This can be compared from different environment configurations or programs.

Comment: Hi Jiayao,
There is no differences expect paths and parameters.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed log to help locate the problem.

Comment: I will close this question, task ignored
thank you